# In Eclipse, I want to make the entire line that starts with "logger.info("... to be grayed out. Is this possible?

Tags: eclipse

My work requires me to add lots of logging statements to my code. This makes the code untidy. So, at least on my IDE, I want these specific lines to be grayed out. Does Eclipse offer some REGEX / rule based color palette capabilities?